# Extend keybindings in JTable

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, key-bindings

After adding a binding for <kbd>F4</kbd> to a `JTable` inside a panel, the standard behavior for <kbd>TAB</kbd> stops working. Instead of the expected jump to the next cell, the current cell goes into edit mode.

This happens when using `ActionMap`/`InputMap` or adding a `KeyListener` to the table

```
ActionMap map = new ActionMap();
map.put("f4Action", new F4Action());
map.setParent(this.getActionMap());

InputMap input = new InputMap();
input.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F4"), "f4Action");
input.setParent(this.getInputMap());

// this is the table in question
table.setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT, input);
table.setActionMap(map);
```

or just `table.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { /*...*/ }` with the other approach.

---

Is it possible to keep the standard behavior and only override explicit keybindings? And how can this be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActionMap map = new ActionMap();
```

Don't create a new `ActionMap`.

Just use the existing `ActionMap`:

```
ActionMap map = table.getActionMap();
```

See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of all the current bindings and templates of how to customize the bindings.

Comment: Thought the solution for overriding a specific key lies in the hierarchy of `InputMap`s. But your solution is simpler, straightforward... and working of course^^